# Need Help Understanding the Meaning of Certain Topics in a Writing Contest

Tags: creative-writing, short-story

I wish to write an entry for a writing contest. The contest requires a piece of 2,000 words, and gives the following four themes or topics that I may choose to write on. But because English is not my mother tongue, I am having difficulty understanding the topic "sentences". The topics are:

1. The Meaning of Me
2. Paved or Unpaved Ways
3. Because This is What Matters, and
4. The Bravest Place on Earth.

I am particularly mystified by the second one, "Paved and Unpaved Ways." What do these topic titles mean? What you think they are asking for?

Comment: It think the second one could be a variation of "The Road Less Travelled" theme - meaning, do you follow in the paths of others on the road that has already been travelled on, or you choose your own way, the one not many people have chosen?

Comment: Does the contest have a website? Perhaps there's more information there.

Comment: @Tannalein You should make that an answer; I think that's pretty much nailed it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding an English sentence, rather than about writing style and techniques.

Comment: @NeilFein Out of curiosity I [found the contest](https://www.facebook.com/KarachiLitFest/posts/572484782796113). It is for the Oxford University Press's 2014 Karachi Literature Festival and it is for 2,000-word short stories written by Pakistanis in English. It's a facebook page and there isn't a lot of information there but there is a comments section where questions are being answered by the sponsors.

Comment: Although I don't think the question can be made to fit this site, and I do think Tannalein's answer is excellent, I feel compelled to put in my two cent's worth, because I just have a sense that "paved or unpaved" suggests "smooth or difficult" more than traveled or untraveled. Although one would usually assume the smooth, paved road would be more traveled, that may not be the point in identifying it that way. Popularity and difficulty are not always based on the same factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one could be a variation of "The Road Less Travelled" theme - meaning, do you follow in the paths of others on the road that has already been travelled on, or you choose your own way, the one not many people have chosen.

They're all pretty general, probably meant to be that way so you can make your own interpretation of what they're supposed to mean to you.